# AppWidget on lockscreen with password

Tags: android, android-appwidget, lockscreen

I have an AppWidget that successfully displays on the lockscreen, even when a password or pin is set.

I have a single button that dials a phone number. When the phone is locked and I click the button, the password field takes focus.

I have tried to find a way for the widget to take focus with no luck. I believe it is possible because, this app does what I want and way more:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.dialerWidget

A few details:

Widget Info

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:minWidth="294dp"
android:minHeight="72dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="10000"  
android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget1"
android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/widget1"
>
```

AppWidgetProvider

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);    
String phone ="555555555";

callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));    
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntent, 0);
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget1);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);
```

Thanks